# debugging a function called from another function with RStudio

Tags: r, debugging, rstudio

I have two scripts, *main.r*

```
# test
a = 1
source("fun.r")
b = fun(a)
c = a + b
```

and *fun.r*

```
# function
fun <- function(a){
    t = a*2
    b = t + 1
}
```

I put a breakpoint in *fun.r* at line 4 `b = t + 1`. The breakpoint is ignored by RStudio. When I run *main.r*, RStudio doesn't stop at line 4 in *fun.r*: as a matter of fact, it doesn't stop at all. How can I debug a function called from another function in RStudio?

Comment: seems like you have to use the source button in rstudio (or keyboard shortcut) which will print `debugSource("fun.r")` to the console, but I still can't get the debugging to work by replacing source with debugSource in your main.r

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R's `source` function does not respect breakpoints. If you want to debug the function, you might try this:

1. Source fun.r (by itself). You will see a copy of `fun()` appear in the environment pane.
2. Add the breakpoint. You will see the copy of `fun()` marked with a breakpoint icon in the environment pane.
3. Remove the line from main.r that sources fun.r (no need since it's already sourced)
4. Source main.r

You'll hit the breakpoint.

The important thing to remember is that a function must already exist in order for you to set a breakpoint on it, and that `source` replaces the copy that has a breakpoint with a new copy that does not have a breakpoint.

Comment: Cool, it works! The procedure is a bit strange (for me), but it does the job, so that's fine.

Comment: You can also replace `source('fun.r')` with `debugSource('fun.r')` in your `main.r` script and then run it in the IDE. It will stop on breakpoints in the `fun.r` file.